Usage of だけ in this sentence: ほんの僅かだけ気配を探ってみる。Adverb or modifying a noun?

先程のこともあり、香苗はほんの僅かだけ気配を探ってみる。感知したのは、この前感じた巴の気配だった。

"Because of what happened before, Kana tries to search a presence. But the only thing she can feel is tomoe's presence (that she also felt the other day)"
The character is trying to "feel" the sign of a friend who is a ghost but the only thing she can feel is their other friend in front of them.
My question is: What does だけ here mean? Is it modifying 気配 hinting the presence she's looking for is faint?

Given the use of も, I think perhaps "in spite of" is more accurate than "because of"... ?

^ 「～のこともあり・～のこともあって・～のこともあるので」 "Partly because of..."  でいいと思いますが。This も is like "partly". cf.「先日のことがあるので」(100%) because of what happened the other day, 「先日のこともあるので」(There might be some other reason but) also because of what happened the other day → Partly because of...

This ほんの僅かだけ means "only slightly", and it adverbially modifies 探る. In other words, she searched only for a very short period of time, with almost no effort.
If this 僅か adjectivally modifies 気配, it must be in the attributive form (僅かな or 僅かだけの):

ほんの僅かな気配を探る
ほんの僅かだけの気配を探る
to search for the slightest sign
ほんの僅か(に)気配を探る
ほんの僅か(に)だけ気配を探る
to search only slightly for signs
to search just a little bit for signs

Note that に after 僅か is occasionally omitted. 僅か can work adverbially without に, just like 少し or ちょっと.

だけ means "only", pretty consistently - it sets a limit on some quantity or set membership.
Japanese particles are post-positions; they describe the preceding element of the sentence.

香苗はほんの僅かだけ気配を探ってみる

The element before だけ is 〖ほんの〗[僅]{わず}か - which is to say, more words connoting the sense of "merely" or "only" or "hint" (in the sense of "not very much") or "trifle".
On the other hand, adverbial and adjectival phrases (to lean on an English grammatical understanding) precede what they're modifying. This entire phrase modifies 気配; thus, Kana senses only the barest possible hint of Tomoe's presence.

This entire phrase modifies 気配 --　ううん。。「ほんの少しだけ気配を探ってみる」と同じ形でほぼ同じ意味です。ほんの僅かだけ≈ほんの少しだけ adverbially modifies 探ってみる

ああ、そうです。 I suppose it would need な the other way...
